# spring integration kafka - pause/seek consumer from my listener for a small time

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

My Spring integration graph looks like below.
[image]

In my service activator, is it possible to get the listener based on my message and then pause it for a while if further down the line, my processing is slow? I would need this way to handle some overflow mechanism.

I see i can implement a new consumerSeekCallback, but in the integration setup, as i understand, i cannot access the messageDrivenChannelAdapter.

I am using ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer linked to message-driven-channel-adapter.

```
    <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaListenertest" listener-container="containertest" auto-startup="true"
    phase="100" send-timeout="5000" channel="kafkaMessage" error-channel="overflow"  />

<bean id="containertest"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg ref="kafkaConsumerFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="consumerContainerPropertiestest" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="4"/>
</bean>

<bean id="consumerContainerPropertiestest"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
    <constructor-arg name="topics" value="events.test" />
    <property name="ackMode" value="MANUAL_IMMEDIATE"></property>
</bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel="kafkaMessage"
    ref="MyListener" method="handleIncomingKafkaEvent" ></int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="kafkaMessage"></int:channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the version `2.1.3`, Spring Kafka provides this API on the `MessageListenerContainer`:

```
/**
 * Pause this container before the next poll().
 * @since 2.1.3
 */
default void pause() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This container doesn't support pause");
}

/**
 * Resume this container, if paused, after the next poll().
 * @since 2.1.3
 */
default void resume() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This container doesn't support resume");
}

/**
 * Return true if {@link #pause()} has been called; the container might not have actually
 * paused yet.
 * @return true if pause has been requested.
 * @since 2.1.5
 */
default boolean isPauseRequested() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This container doesn't support pause/resume");
}

/**
 * Return true if {@link #pause()} has been called; and all consumers in this container
 * have actually paused.
 * @return true if the container is paused.
 * @since 2.1.5
 */
default boolean isContainerPaused() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This container doesn't support pause/resume");
}
```

So, you really can pause and resume your listener container from any point of your application injecting that `containertest` into an appropriate service.

The `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` also exposes `pause()` and `resume()` hooks.

Also, in the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`, the `MessagingMessageConverter` populates these headers into the message for downstream processing:

```
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, record.key());
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, record.topic());
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, record.partition());
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, record.offset());
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.TIMESTAMP_TYPE, record.timestampType().name());
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP, record.timestamp());

    if (acknowledgment != null) {
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, acknowledgment);
    }
    if (consumer != null) {
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER, consumer);
    }
```

So, you can obtain a `KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER` header and use an native `pause()/resume()` from the `KafkaConsumer`.

Comment: i just noticed that i bound to use spring kafka1.3.4 and spring integration kafka 2.3.0. Not able to upgrade immediately. Can we do something like this in these versions?

Comment: No, sorry: we can't.

Comment: On the other hand in most cases we don't need to worry about pause/resume since there is a background heart-beat task from the `consumer` even if your listener is blocked.

Comment: basically i dont want the consumer to poll if my listener is busy/not able to accept more. would like to poll for more messages when listener becomes free a little seconds later.

Comment: Well, if it's busy, it's definitely not going to poll. You can add some `Thread.sleep()` in the end of process meanwhile you can't upgrade to the latest Spring Kafka